# Making several copies of a file replacing some word with bash or python

Tags: python, bash, file, copy-paste

I have a some file *my_file*. I have a list (of length n) of words and I want to make n copies of the file with elements from the list appended at the end of the file and also changing all words 'x' met in my_file with the corresponding entity from the list.

For example : if my file is

```
----my_file.txt---
This is my x file
------------------
```

and my list is {a,b,c} I want three files : my_filea.txt, my_fileb.txt and my_filec.txt and in each of them the letter x changed to a,b,c, accordingly.

It is convenient for me to do this with bash or python.
Any suggestions?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour], read about [ask], particularly how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Pseudo-code: loop on the values in your list:  "calculate" the new filename, read the lines from the input file, replace the x by the value of the current iteration of the loop, output that to the new file, next loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the python script to do that .

```
import re
data=open("myfile.txt","r").read()
listinput=['a','b','c']
for i in listinput:
    changed_data=re.sub("x file",i+" file",data)
    fp2=open("myfile"+i+".txt","w")
    fp2.write(changed_data)
    fp2.close()
```